# Balanced Graph Communities With Node Weights

Tags: mathematical-statistics, clustering, graph-theory

I'm looking for where best to start on the following problem.

I have a graph of N nodes and each node as a weight. I need to group all nodes into X groups such that the sum of weights in each group are approximately even and that each group is a connected component of the original graph.

After some simple searching I came across the lukes partitioning algorithm implemented in python.

https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.community.lukes.lukes_partitioning.html#networkx.algorithms.community.lukes.lukes_partitioning

This is approximately what I am looking for but performance feels slow for the size of the graph I am working with.

Do you have any potentially better ideas that worked for you?